# Display an image using readfile() from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

To test `readfile()`, I put the following code at the very top of the main index.php file, and the image displayed correctly. However, when I put the EXACT same code in my controller, it just displays a broken image.

I tried replacing the header line with `"$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');"`, but just got scrambled characters. How can I get it to display from the controller as it does from the index file? I'm stumped.

Code:

```
$file = '/home/www/noname.com/public/captcha/1444721011.7843.jpg';
 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
exit;
```

I tried putting "header_remove();" in the controller before the code. The result was still just a broken image (despite the headers looking identical). Like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2166
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 12:27:43 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I do notice that on all of my pages there is one empty line before <!DOCTYPE html> . See an example of what I mean at the top of this link which is also a codeigniter site. view-source:call2you.co . I'm wondering if that could be the cause. Any idea where that line comes from so I can remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you remove the `exit` call, your example should be working fine in a controller.

If you really want to abort script execution, then your method should look like this:

```
public function display_image () {
    $file = '/home/www/noname.com/public/captcha/1444721011.7843.jpg';
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $this->output
            ->set_status_header(200)
            ->set_content_type('image/jpeg')
            ->set_output($contents)
            ->_display();
    exit;
}
```

Which should allow a clean exit.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately removing exit didn't change anything. Neither did your code. I do notice that on all of my pages there is one empty line before <!DOCTYPE html> . See an example of what I mean at the top of this link which is also a codeigniter site. view-source:http://call2you.co/ . I'm wondering if that could be the cause. Any idea where that comes from?

Comment: Looks like you're outputing an empty line somewhere in your code, Or you have a new line before an opening php tag '<?php' ... anyway if that new line is the problem then if you try to save the corrupted image file & open it in a text editor you should be able to see 'Headers already sent' error ... this won't be displayed in the browser because you're sending it content-type:image/jpeg.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. That was the issue. As I mentioned below, I resolved it with ob_end_clean();. As far as the 'Headers already sent' error goes, was sending content-type:image/jpeg preventing it from appearing in the error log on the server too? Because that wasn't showing me anything.

Comment: If you have display_errors set to on, then your errors goes to browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here. The problem was the empty line that was mysteriously being added at the top of the source code. Finding the source of that line was becoming too time-consuming, so my solution was to just put ob_end_clean(); before the header. So:

```
     $file = '/home/www/noname.com/public/captcha/1444721011.7843.jpg';
     ob_end_clean();
     $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
     readfile($file);
```

Thank you, those who responded.